# Finding out if a dictionary's elements are bigger than those from an other dictionary

Tags: python

I want to have a loop (for example a While-Loop) that checks if all elements of an dictionary are bigger than those from an other dictionary. 
Those are the requirement dictionary and 2 examples dictionaries to check:

```
requirements = {"happiness":9, "money": 100}

person1 = {"happiness": 15, "money": 3200}
person2 = {"happiness": 4, "money": 5000}
```

And the While loop would look like this:

```
while person >= requirements:
    p = Counter(person)
    p.subtract(requirements)
    person = dict(p)
```

When it's checking if the person fulfills the requirements, I want it to only be True if ALL requirements are fulfilled.

NOTE: The Part inside the while-loop where the requirements get subtracted from the person can be ignored, it has nothing to do with the questions but it is the code I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need explicit loops in Python to solve this kind of problem, use comprehensions like this:

```
all(value > requirements[key] for key, value in person1.items())
```

Comment: I probably could have figured that out too when I would think a little longer :D But this is exactly the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the `while` loop is for but I think a simple `for` loop would suffice in this case.

```
from operator import gt

people = [person1, person2]
for person in people:
    thresholds = [gt(person.get(k), requirements.get(k, 0)) for k in person.keys()]
    if all(thresholds):
        print(f'Person --> {person} meets requirements')

Person --> {'happiness': 15, 'money': 3200} meets requirements
```

NOTE: f-strings only works on >= Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Hope my question will give you inspiration. My function `bigger_than_reqiurements()` checking one `person` using all keys it can find in `require`. It return `True` only if **all** values are bigger then `reqiure`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def bigger_than_requirements(person, require):
    for key in require:
        if person[key] <= require[key]:
            return False

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_persons = [{"happiness": 15, "money": 3200},
                   {"happiness": 4, "money": 5000}]
    requirements = {"happiness": 9, "money": 100}

    for person in all_persons:
        if bigger_than_requirements(person, requirements):
            print('Bigger: {}'.format(person))
```

You could also add an exception handling for a `KeyError` if a key is not present in `person`.

```
try:
    if person[key] <= require[key]:
        return False
except KeyError:
    return False
```